# Match variable length of string with hyphen , not with underscore and not German special character in oracle REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: java, regex, oracle

I want to match a string which start with char (A-Z) and can have up to 6 word and 2 number like:
ABD00,
ABCDEFG12,
A-SDS12,
DXSDV1-12,

but I don't want string which have underscore "_" or any German special character like "äöüßÄÖÜ"
So word which i want restrict is like:
AAA_AAA12,
A_14,
AAAAAAAA09,
AÖAAAAA09

```
-- wokring
select 1 from dual where REGEXP_LIKE ('AAUT-PI09', '^[A-Z]\w{1,6}|-{1,6}\d{2}');
-- not working
select 1 from dual where REGEXP_LIKE ('A-AUTPI09', '^[A-Z]\w{1,6}|-{1,6}\d{2}');

-- working
select 1 from dual where REGEXP_LIKE ('AAAAAß09', '^[A-Z]\w[^_|^ä|^ö|^ü|^ß|^Ä|^Ö|^Ü]{1,6}\d{2}');
-- but should not work for
select 1 from dual where REGEXP_LIKE ('AAAAAAAA09', '^[A-Z]\w[^_|^ä|^ö|^ü|^ß|^Ä|^Ö|^Ü]{1,6}\d{2}');

-- work for below
select 1 from dual where REGEXP_LIKE ('AA_AAAA09', '^[A-Z]\w[^_|^ä|^ö|^ü|^ß|^Ä|^Ö|^Ü]{1,6}\d{2}$');
-- but should not work for 
select 1 from dual where REGEXP_LIKE ('A_AAAAA09', '^[A-Z]\w[^_|^ä|^ö|^ü|^ß|^Ä|^Ö|^Ü]{1,6}\d{2}$');
```

and how to restrict German special character and underscore "_" from 2 to 6 position in string?

Comment: Side note: Your table/database needs to be using a collation which supports German characters.

Comment: Probably easier with two conditions. It should be something like `'[A-Z][-A-Z0-9]{1,5}\d{2}'`. That is no `\w` as that includes an underscore. The hyphen at begin or end of the `[...]` so as not to mean a range like `A-Z`.